# Is there anything different about a h1 and h2 and other heading tags aside from size?

Tags: html, css

I am learning web development at the moment. I like using CSS to have all the style stuff separately. I was wondering if there is any different between a h2 tag that has just been made bigger using CSS and a h1 tag?

Comment: It just has to do the level/index of the heading. The only difference is the `font-size`, but like all other elements, either can be manipulated with CSS

Comment: @BeerusDev — The visual rendering is **not** the only difference.

Comment: @Quentin if the visual rendering is what sets the tone for that headings priority, then what else is the difference?

Comment: @BeerusDev — Not every entity that consumes a web page uses a visual medium to do so. Consider screen readers or search engines or table-of-contents generators.

Comment: @Quentin ahhh. Thank you